# Scrolling effect with animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem. I'm using animate.css to add into my elements animations but I want that the animations start when I scroll the website to the next section and when I return to a page, they start again.

How can I do that? Thanks

P.S: I use bootstrap for my website.

Comment: *I'm using animate.css

Comment: Edit your post. Add the website link to "animate css", show us what you've tried, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for triggering animate.css effects when a section/element comes into view, you can use [CSS3 Animate It](http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit/examples) plugin. I have used it and it's good for this purpose.